# Check if user exists in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I've made a user class which validates the data passed through the form and then subsequently updates the database table users. I want to add extra functionality such as checking if the username and email exists in the table, I've added a little script however it doesn't seem to be working.

I inserted a duplicated email address and I did not get the error message "email exists" instead I get the success message "1 row inserted":

Am I doing something wrong below? Is there perhaps a better way to approach this?

```
 public function insert() {

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';

$result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");

if ($result->num_rows) {
echo "email exisits!";
} 
 else
 {
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $name, $email); // bind strings to the paramater
        //escape the POST data for added protection

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : '';
$cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);
$password = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($cryptedPassword);
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';
        /* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
    /* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe if you added a `UNIQUE` index on `email` you could effectively prevent multiple users with the same email.

Comment: Use
    /* execute query */
    $result->execute();

    /* store result */
    $result->store_result();
and then use $result->num_rows()

Comment: Mind you, your code is bloated and wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok thanks for your insightful comment

Comment: @vishalshah no I haven't I will try this now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the worst API you ever can choose.

With safeMysql it would be

```
$exists = $this->db->getOne("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=?s", $_POST['email']);
if ($exists) {
    echo "email exisits!";
}
```

With PDO it is slightly longer but usable

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['email']));
$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ($exists)
{
    echo "email exisits!";
}
```

But with raw mysqli you will need a screenful of code only to check if user exists.

So, the whole function using safeMysql would be

```
public function insert()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=?s";
    $exists = $this->db->getOne($sql, $_POST['email']);
    if ($exists)
    {
        echo "email exisits!";
        return FALSE;

    }
    $sql     = "INSERT INTO users SET ?u";
    $allowed = array('username', 'name', 'email');
    $insert  = $this->db->filterArray($_POST, $allowed);
    $insert['password'] = crypt($_POST['password']);
    $this->db->query($sql, $insert);
    return $this->db->afectedRows();
}
```

Comment: thanks will look into PDO, also I thought prepared statements were good practice? @YourCommonSense

Comment: or is it just the use of MySQLi? @YourCommonSense

Comment: prepared statements are good practice but you are using them wrong way.

Comment: ok i see, can you give me an example of the correct way vs my way so I'm aware of this please @YourCommonSense

Comment: I gave a couple examples already in my answer. Burhan Khalid's one contains another

Comment: ok thanks will do some further research, appreciate the help @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this code after prepare statement

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

put this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "email exisits!";
}
```

instead of

```
if ($result->num_rows) {
echo "email exisits!";
}
```

Comment: did work, do I need to bind my results etc like Im doing below?

Comment: you need to use store_result() for using num_rows

Comment: and you need to use $stmt->execute(); after insert query prepare statement

Comment: I kinda like the way this **completely wrong** answer was eventually edited after its author learned the right one from other comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  what do you mean?

Comment: I hope my statement above is quite clean and comprehensible.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  i am not getting you what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using `prepare` (great!) but then you are just passing in the value of email, effectively defeating the benefit of prepared statements.

Second, you never execute the query, which is why you don't get anything in `num_rows`.

```
public function insert() {

$result = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=?");
$result->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($email_count);

if ($email_count) {
    echo "email exisits!";
} else {
   # your other logic
```

Comment: I implemented this but I get the following error: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in E:\xampp\htdocs\imanage\insert.php on line 52`
`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\imanage\insert.php on line 60` I've only defined one variable which is email so dont understand the error messages, any suggestions? @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Nope, his idea is a proper one

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see you're not assigning a value to num_rows prior to testing it with if ($result->num_rows), so it will always be 0